# HTTP 500 response is received when using C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I have developed a C# application that calls a REST service existing in some PC in the network.

This is the code to make a request:

```
    public async Task<bool> OpenDoorAsync(string name, int delay)
    {
        var data = await CallApiAsync("api/door/remoteOpenByName", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "doorName", name }, { "interval", delay.ToString() } });
        return data.IsSuccess;
    }

    private async Task<ResponseData> CallApiAsync(string endPoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");

                var content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                string fullUri = "http://192.168.0.122:8088/api/door/remoteOpenByName?doorName=10.185.85.237-1&interval=5&access_token=1234";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(fullUri, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(responseBody);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnError("Existió un error al realizar la llamada.", ex);
            return new ResponseData()
            {
                message = "failed"
            };
        }
    }
```

Entry point is `OpenDoorAsync`, called this way, from a Winform form:

```
await _device.OpenDoorAsync(TxtNombrePuerta.Text.Trim(), IntInterval.Value);
```

Well, after the execution of `PostAsync` method, a HTTP 500 error is returned:

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2021 21:06:35 GMT
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4062B932CDB44B4CA3FCCC275937AC15; Path=/; HttpOnly
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 2580
  Content-Language: en
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

However, if I make the same request using Google Chrome RESTED extension, it works perfectly:

[image: RESTED call]

Just in case, I analyzed Google Chrome developer tools after the RESTED call and I have not found anything weird. I thought maybe I missed to send something else in the headers.

[image: Developer tools]

Does anybody know what is happening with the call from the C# application? Clearly, I am not doing something that RESTED is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why it does not work when using `HttpClient` class, however, I solved the problem installling an using RestSharp NuGet package.

Finally, the code was reduced to this:

```cs
private ResponseData CallApi(string endPoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    try
    {
        string fullUri = $"http://{GetServerIp()}:{((MainWindow)MainWindow).ServerPort}/{endPoint}?{GetQueryParameters(parameters)}";
        var client = new RestClient(fullUri);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(response.Content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnError("Existió un error al realizar la llamada.", ex);
        return new ResponseData()
        {
            message = "failed"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't used RestSharp before. You could run fiddler or wireshark or similar and look at the requests being made by each class. I'm sure there was something simple that we weren't picking up on in the HttpClient method...

The one major difference I see here is that you aren't even trying to send a body where you were sending a blank one in the previous code.

Either way, congrats on solving the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your working example is passing cookies, which may be required for the API you're calling.

Comment: Also, you're not using your `endPoint` parameter. That isn't causing your problem, but I thought I'd point it out. You should either build up your URL using the parameter or just remove the parameter.

Comment: I have hardcoded the URL to narrow down the problem. The real case is using endpoint parameter. The fact is that there are not post parameters to send. The only way I thought was to send a StringContent with an empty body. I used `application/json` as one of the tests. About RESTED tests, it works if POST parameters are `Custom`, `JSON` or `URL Encoded form data`. If I choose `Multipart form data`, the call also returns a HTTP 500 error (however, different reason), but I agree with you that maybe the problem are the parameters, but I wonder how to  not pass parameters.

Comment: By the way, the parameters are passed in the query string, not the post body.

Comment: Sorry for all the iterations on my answer. I've removed the items from my original answer that don't appear to be relevant given your working example. The only thing I see that seems likely now is the cookie header being included from RESTED.

Comment: Something that might be helpful would be to use the `ToString` method on your response's `RequestMessage` property. That will give a string including all the headers that were sent, which you could compare to dev tools for RESTED.

Comment: I think Chrome is the responsible to send the cookie. If this may help, the docs of the rest api shows the following example of calling, using `curl` utility: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://192.168.0.122:8088/api/door/remoteOpenByName?doorName=10.185.85.237-1&interval=5'`. I saw I missed the `Accept` header, but I added it this way: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json");`... but the same error. I will do what you suggest about calling ToString.

Comment: This is the result of RequestMessage.ToString(): `Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://192.168.0.122:8088/api/door/remoteOpenByName?doorName=10.185.85.237-1&interval=5&access_token=1234', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Accept: application/json\r\n  Connection: keep-alive\r\n  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n  Content-Length: 0\r\n}`

Comment: There is no a cookie problem. The only reason is how the C# call is being made. I have found that `curl` utility is also under Windows 10, so I ran `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" "http://192.168.0.122:8088/api/door/remoteOpenByName?doorName=10.185.85.237-1&interval=5&access_token=1234"` and it worked!!

Comment: I have also run only: `curl -X POST "http://192.168.0.122:8088/api/door/remoteOpenByName?doorName=10.185.85.237-1&interval=5&access_token=1234"` and it also worked. It is very strange why from C# it does not work.

Comment: By using HttpWebRequest object it does not work either. I am wondering what the C# program is trying to do

Comment: It finallly worked! I installed RestSharp NuGet package, and with 3 lines of code, it works. Code results very reduced but I didn't know what I was missing when using HttpClient class or WebRequest class. That is a mystery.